# GUI для консольного приложения (выполнение команд после запуска)

Tags: c#, gui, консоль, execute

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, решил создать GUI для консольного приложения, запускаю его так.

```
MyProc.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
MyProc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
MyProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
MyProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
MyProc.Start();
if (waitforexit)
    MyProc.WaitForExit();
```

Запускается приложение с ключом без проблем, но как передать этому приложению ещё одну команду? Запускать заново - не вариант, т.к приложение запускается таким образом

```
cProgram.exe file_name
```

И дальше идет выполнение команд внутри cProgram

```
(cProgram) write_some_comand
```

Как быть?

Comment: [Практическое руководство. Использование именованных каналов для взаимодействия между процессами по сети](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb546085.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обмениваться с приложением через пайп. Вот пример (delphi): [консольный редирект в обе стороны](http://www.cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread11655.html).

Еще лучше пример тут: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx). Но это WinAPI.

Comment: Я не думаю что все так сложно, и вообще, последняя ссылка это что вообще такое и как она ко мне относится?

Comment: По последней ссылке производится запуск дочернего приложения с перенаправлением ввода (stdin/stdout) в родительское, т.е. родитель после запуска дочернего приложения может продолжать общаться с ним через пайп, а дочернее приложение в это даже вникать не будет, для него это будет "простое общение через консоль ввода".

Т.е. printf и scanf в дочернем приложении будут печатать и запрашивать данные в/из пайпа родителя, а не в/из консоли.

Такая вот подмена каналов производится в этом примере.

Answer (score 3):

Послать в консоль команду:

```
myProc.StandardInput.WriteLine("write_some_comand\r\n");
myProc.StandardInput.Flush();
```

---

Можно также создать процесс, не показывая самой консоли:

```
myProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне подсказывает [`winapi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc433218%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) ([`sendmessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.messagewindow.sendmessage%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [`postmessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.messagewindow.postmessage%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

Общий алгоритм таков: ищете название окна (тоже winapi FindWindow), получаете handle окна и по это handle отправляете message (можно стандартные, WM_CLOSE, etc.). Или же делаете свой, кастомный message-list-parameters.